# Add new textview in fragment after click on button in another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview

I have two fragments. After I click on button in the first one, it moves to the second fragment with some SharedPreferences. Everytime I click on that button, I want to add new textview under another with text from SharedPreferences in the second fragment.

Here is code from second fragment where I want to add textviews

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String Income =sharedPreferences.getString("Income","N/A");

        LinearLayout m_ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home);

        m_ll.addView(createNewTextView(Income));
        return m_ll;
    }

    private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
        final LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("New text: " + text);
        return textView;
    }
}
```

It add textview with correct text, but next time when I press the button it just change text of the textview (or create one textview on another?)

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/home"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.xxxx.HomeFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it create only one textview as inflated layout will not contain your original textview anymore. You need to save your data in the form of array of strings and based on array length, create that many textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with TinyDB, which can store string arraylist as SharedPreferences.

This is what I have in fragment with button

```
TinyDB tinydb=new TinyDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    incometemp = edttxt.getText().toString();
    mylist= tinydb.getListString("income");
    mylist.add(incometemp );
    tinydb.putListString("income", mylist);
```

Second fragment

```
TinyDB tinydb;
    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        tinydb = new TinyDB(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mylist = tinydb.getListString("income");
        LinearLayout m_ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home);

        for (int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
            m_ll.addView(createNewTextView(mylist.get(i)));
        }


        return m_ll;
    }

    private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
        final LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("New text: " + text);
        return textView;
    }
}
```